# How to Add Google Map in website using mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I am doing this first time, how can I add google map in my website? I have done AJAX please see this code and give me answer

The area that comes throw database using AJAX, Area are perfectly done and "latitude" & "longitude" are perfectly got it, but I can't use that latitude & longitude in JavaScript code.

this is my php file code is:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select name="area_id" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)" id="area">
                                    <option value="">Select Area</option>
                                </select>

</div>
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
</div>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

this is getuser.php file:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" My Map Key "&callback=initMap"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #txtHint {
                height: 350px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
        $q = intval($_GET['q']);


        echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM area WHERE area_id='$q'";
                $qry = mysql_query($sql);
                while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {

                    $area_name=$fetch['area_name'];
                    //$city_name=$fetch['city_name'];

                    $address =$area_name; // Google HQ

                                        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
                                        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
                                        $output= json_decode($geocode);
                                        $area_latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;

                                        $area_longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

                                        echo "<br><input type='text' name='area_latitude' id='area_latitude'value='".$area_latitude."'> <br>";
                                        echo "<input type='text' name='area_longitude' id='area_longitude' value='".$area_longitude."'>";
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var marker;
                var area_latitude = $("#area_latitude").val();
                var area_longitude = $("#area_longitude").val();

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(area_latitude, area_longitude);
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 18,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("txtHint"), mapOptions);

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: myLatlng,
                        draggable: true
                    });


                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'latLng': myLatlng
                    }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

                        geocoder.geocode({
                            'latLng': marker.getPosition()
                        }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[0]) {
                                    $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>

            <?php   }
        ?>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the console?  Does any map appear?

Comment: Remove this: `"&callback=initMap"` from where you load the map script.  You already cover this when you do `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: i was remove this "&callback=initMap" but not working...

Answer (score 0):

The values being returned by this are probably strings (`"1.2345"`) instead of Floats (`1.2345`), which is what the Google Maps expects for coordinates:

```
var area_latitude = $("#area_latitude").val();
var area_longitude = $("#area_longitude").val();
```

Try:

```
var area_latitude = parseFloat($("#area_latitude").val());
var area_longitude = parseFloat($("#area_longitude").val());
```

Comment: sir it is not working, i got the latitude & longitude bit whenever i will set in script that time it is not working, i will run direct getuser.php that time it is perfectly run but whenever using with AJAX that time only JavaScript not run

Comment: Where's your AJAX request in your question?  The problem is because you're calling `initialize` before the AJAX response happens.

Comment: whenever i will change Area dropdown that time onchange="showUser(this.value)" method call and this method code mention in above 1st php file in question

Comment: sir if you have team viewer then i will give my id and password to check this problem